# MonoTouch UIWebView and EvaluateJavascript 

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, mono, xamarin.ios

I have an application working on the following envirnoment:

- Monotouch 2.1
- MonoDevelop 2.4.2
- MacOS 10.6.8
- iOS SDK 4.3

The same application, migrated to iOS 5.0/5.1 and Monotouch 5.2.10 with MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4 under, has the following problem: When i click a button to navigate in a UIWebView do not work.

Code is that:(obviously it's same in Monotouch 2.1)

```
public void ScrollToTop (object sender, EventArgs evt)
{
    webView.EvaluateJavascript("window.scrollTo(0,0)");
}
```

What could i do?

SOLVED (with Jonathan.Peppers help):

```
public void ScrollToTop (object sender, EventArgs evt)
{
    if((UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckVersion(5, 0)){                 
                System.Drawing.PointF p = new System.Drawing.PointF(0, 0);
                webView.ScrollView.SetContentOffset(p,true);
            }
            else{
                webView.EvaluateJavascript("window.scrollTo(0,0)");                 
            }
}
```

i have made in that way because on 4.3 webView.ScrollView.SetContentOffset make application crash.

Comment: You can also use: `if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckVersion(5, 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string error = webView.EvaluateJavascript("try { window.scrollTo(0,0); } catch (e) { return e.message; }");
```

*(double check my code)*

It should get you a better error message.  Tell us the value of the string returned.

I suspect the issue isn't MonoTouch, but perhaps iOS5?  Safari had drastic changes in iOS5, new javascript engine, etc.

Comment: Excellent observation. In fact on iOS 4.3 works fine, instead on iOS 5 no. I have tried to execute your code but there are no exceptions and there are no errors written on string error.  How do you think can solve?

Comment: This question has a couple examples that might do what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506958/how-to-find-in-javascript-the-current-scroll-offset-in-mobile-safari-iphon.  They are in Objective-C, but should be easy to pull out the javascript

Comment: I have solved in that way: i have check which iOS is running and i have execute different operation. i have update my question with answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `UIWebView` is not [re-entrant](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIWebView.LoadRequest%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlRequest%29). If the way of loading the (or just the timing of) page changes between iOS release then this may become a problem.

To avoid this just make sure you're not calling back into *any* `UIWebView` instance until the loading is completed, e.g. [`LoadFinished`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIWebView.LoadFinished) or `LoadError` is called.

If this does not help then please create a small, self-contained, test case that duplicate the issue and attach it to a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com