# easiest javascript bridge for monotouch uiwebview using c# - xamarin ios

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Really struggling to find an active solution that would enable 2 way communication between monotouch (c#) to uiwebview.

Android seems to do this well with JavaScriptInterface.

(Trying to get leaflet.js working inside a Xamarin IOS uiwebview component with geojson downloaded so i can populate leaflet.js sitting in the uiwebview and also listen to js callbacks from native side).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this sample:

https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/ContentControls

And previous questions on StackOverflow:

[How I can call a javascript function with MonoTouch and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399706/how-i-can-call-a-javascript-function-with-monotouch-and-vice-versa)

[MonoTouch UIWebView and EvaluateJavascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087489/monotouch-uiwebview-and-evaluatejavascript)

Or full blog posts:

http://yobriefca.se/blog/2011/12/05/rolling-your-own-phonegap-with-monotouch/

Comment: Thanks Miguel.  Would be great if the Mapbox IOS SDK got officially converted for monotouch in full, at some point. :)