# JQuery: How to access scroll height / Y offset on IPad/Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know a reliable method to access the scroll height on an Ipad/ mobile Safari?

Basically I need to access the ipad equivalent of -

```
 $(document).scrollTop();
```

Comment: The only difference between an iphone and ipad safari browser would be the view port. So i think the ipad equivalent would be - $(document).scrollTop(); and nothing else.

Comment: @bhb - I've had no luck with scrollTop on the iPad.

Comment: Paul and @Peter - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506958/how-to-find-in-javascript-the-current-scroll-offset-in-mobile-safari-iphon

Comment: @mccannf - Thanks.  It turned out that I was having so much trouble because my page was actually being rendered in an iFrame.  So while the parent page would scroll the iFrame always had an offset of 0... I ended up having to use "parent." to perform actions.