# React trigger effect on scroll position

Tags: reactjs, animation, scroll, viewport

I have to implement some custom animation on some component after it gets into the viewport, in desktop mode it should be triggered on

> window.scrollY > 1200

it works on desktop but not on mobile mode, the problem is in mobile mode my window.scrollY never gets to 1200.

How should I manage the responsiveness of scrolling effect like this?

```
export default function Layout() {


    const [navColor, setNavColor] = useState(null);
    const [x, setX] = useState(null);

    const pop = () => {
        console.log(window.scrollY);
        if(window.scrollY > 1200){
            setX(classes.Swipe);
        }
       

        if(window.scrollY > 927) {
            setNavColor('red');
        }
        else{
            setNavColor(null);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => pop());

    return (
        <div className={classes.Layout}>
            
            <Video/>
            <Navbar color={navColor}/>
            <Picture />
            <AboutMe />
            <div className={classes.c}>tessdfsdfsfdst div</div>
            <div className={[ x,classes.Div].join(' ')}>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256432/get-current-position-of-the-viewport-in-mobile-iphone-safari . Side node: you add the pop handler every time you rerender your component. You should use the useEffect hook to only add the listener once!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add your event when component mounts, and remove it when unmounts (for safety and performace):

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', pop);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', pop);
},[]);
```

Then your function could be:

```
const pop = () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 1200) {
    setX(classes.Swipe);
  }
           
  if (window.scrollY > 927) {
    setNavColor('red');
  }
      
  setNavColor(null);
}
```

Then detecting if is mobile, you can do:

```
function isMobile() {
  return window.innerWidth <= 800;
}
```

Comment: Why do eslint warnings me this one? "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'pop'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"